# SQLite getCount() returns 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to make search history through SQLite in Android Studio.
When I try to get information from SQLite DB using getCount(),
it keeps returning 0.

I have checked if there are any data in DB by terminal.
However it showed results that there are data.
Please help me.

```
public String[][] getResult(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM AlYak_History", null);

        Log.d("getCount", valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        String[][] result = new String[cursor.getCount()][];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i ++){
                result[cursor.getPosition()][i] = cursor.getString(i+1);
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Use String.valueOf

Comment: Log.d("getCount", cursor.getCount());

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you connect to the DB? Your constructor should be like this:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

It should be `String.valueOf()` not `valueOf`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes I am sure about connecting to DB using Helper and String.valueOf(). But still doesn't work...

Comment: Test it with ```Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM AlYak_History", new String[]{});``` and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me

```
public int getResultCount() {
String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
int cnt = cursor.getCount();
cursor.close();
return cnt;
```

}